# Support hypothesis with use of neither

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

> The accuracy of ranges values seems not crucial,
>   as neither the number of bands is.

What I want to express is the fact that because the exact number of bands is not important, we don't have to care to calculate their borders accurately (its about signal processing, I hope the larger context is not needed to understand this particular sentence, if so, then let me know.)

My friend, who generally knows English better than me, says it is incorrect, there can't be *as* used this the sentence and there should be some attribute after *is*. But I'm not able to formulate it other way. I don't want to begin with *the number of bands*, because before I describe how I calculate *the ranges*, so I want them to appear in the first part of the sentence.

Comment: Why not say it this way: "The accuracy of the range values is not crucial, because the exact number of bands is not important"?

Comment: I think it's ok, but I find "because" a bit too informal for this case.

Comment: You can go archaic and formal: "... not crucial, **for** the exact number..." I don't think that **because** is _informal_, but that may be an idiosyncrasy of mine.

Comment: This would be nice for "Bible of Signal Processing" :) I hope there's something in between your two proposals.

Comment: There's no other one-word solution but **since**, which I think is informal and sometimes ambiguous. I always use "because (of)" instead of the ever-popular "due to (the fact that)".

Comment: So you think my original proposal is not valid?

Comment: Correct. I think the sentence is ungrammatical. Maybe: "Neither the accuracy of range values nor the number of bands is crucial".

Comment: There's also **"due to"** which I think is quite formal and much clearer.

Comment: @BillFranke: That depends (or, for that matter, not.) The *as* suggests (at least to me) the latter is the cause of the former. The "neither...nor" doesn't create any precedence or dependency between the clauses.

Comment: @SF.: I think that perhaps the original is in British English. It's not grammatical American English. I also think that "neither" is misused. I think I'll drop out of the conversation now. My suggestions have been fruitless so far.

Comment: The allegedly informal _because_ seems like much less of a transgression than the rather awkwardly placed _neither_.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the sentence I see is:

> The accuracy of ranges values **seems** not crucial, as neither the number of bands **is**.

If the number of bands merely doesn't seem to be crucial, first, it would be *does*, and then the effect-cause relation emphasized by "as" becomes dubious.

If the number of bands essentially is not crucial, then the *neither* is binding two negative clauses depending on different, non-synonymous verbs: *"Joe is unhappy and neither does Kate eat any candies."*

Besides, I think you're trying to emphasize formality over clarity. The sentence requires conscious effort to process, and as such the meaning is obscured. This is bad writing. It might be welcome if you were a lawyer or a politician, but it's definitely unwelcome in scientific or technical text, where conveying the information clearly is of superior importance to sounding profound or elaborate. Don't hesitate to use simple words where fancy ones obscure the meaning.